# EC2, RHEL - No Route To Domain

Tags: amazon-ec2, routes

This is probably incredibly simple and I'm just missing one step.  The problem I was (originally) trying to solve was how to get a statically allocated hostname, one that would not change with each restart.  I've done the following steps:

I have a domain registered on GoDaddy, and it points to my EIP.  I use it to connect over SSH (putty) to my EC2 instance, so I know that part is working.  I've opened ports 9080, 9060, 9043, and 9443 as well as SSH and FTP ports.  And I've installed and started the software that uses those ports, and that stuff normally just works on a local RHEL install, so I think what's different here is the custom domain name.

I've added my EIP and fully qualified host name to my /etc/hosts file.

I've added my fully qualified host name to my /etc/hostname file and modified the /etc/rc.local script to set the hostname properly on a restart, and that works.  If I execute the command hostname, it returns my fully qualified hostname, so that looks ok.

I cannot ping my server, but I think that's ok, because probably amazon blocks pings.  So I don't think that's a symptom of anything.

I cannot open a to http://myserver.mydomain:9080/, which normally just works.  Here it just times out.

If I do a wget http://myserver.mydomain:9080 from inside the EC2 instance, it returns failed: No Route To Host

But if I do a wget against localhost instead of the fully qualified name I get what I expect as a response.

So.... routing tables?  Do those need to change?  And if so how?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do what you did. Everything in EC2 is NAT'd. Meaning that the IP assigned to your instance is a private/internal ip and the public IP is mapped to it by the routing system.

So internally, you want everything to resolve to the private IP, or you will get charged for traffic as it has to get routed to the edge and then route back in. Using the public DNS name will resolve correctly from the default DNS servers.

If you are using RHEL, you will need to make sure both the security group and the internal firewall (iptables) have ports opened. You could just disable the internal firewall since its a bit redundant with the security groups. On the other hand, it can provide some options security groups do not if you need them.

Comment: I *thought* I wanted the internal traffic to stay internal, that makes sense. But I'd received conflicting advice, or else I'd misunderstood it. Yes, I definitely want internal traffic to stay internal.  So, what then? Remove the hosts file entry? Or point it to the internal IP?

And yes, I'd forgotten about the RHEL internal firewall.  I'll have to fix that as well.